# Node Redis throws read ETIMEDOUT error after some time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis

After a few minutes of inactivity Node Redis always throws `read ETIMEDOUT` error and stops the application.

Using simple `expess.js` application and redis client.

```
redis.createClient({
  url: "redis://default:user@123.123.12.123:6379"
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After different tries to figure out what's wrong I have found a solution to add `pingInterval` option to Redis config, so the connection is always alive.

This config fixed my issue:

```
redis.createClient({
  url: "redis://default:user@123.123.12.123:6379",
  pingInterval: 1000 // <- add pingInterval
});
```